# using stringwriter getting encoding problems

Tags: java, stringwriter

i have used

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
request.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");
pw =response.getWriter();
IOUtils.copy(sImage, writer);
theString = writer.toString();
pw.write(theString);
pw.flush();
```

In the client browser am getting output as

ÿþ<�h�t�m�l� �x�m�l�n�s�:�v�=�"�u�r�n�:�s�c�h�e�m�a�s�-�m�i�c�r�o�s�o�f�t�-�c�o�m�:�v�m�l�"� � �x�m�l�n�s�:�o�=�"�u�r�n�:�s�c�h�e�m�a�s�-�m�i�c�r�o�s�o�f�t�-�c�o�m�:�o�f�f�i�c�e�:�o�f�f�i�c�e�"� � �x�m�l�n�s�:�w�=�"�u�r�n�:�s�c�h�e�m�a�s�-�m�i�c�r�o�s�o�f�t�-�c�o�m�:�o�f�f�i�c�e�:�w�o�r�d�"� � �x�m�l�n�s�:�x�=�"�u�r�n�:�s�c�h�e�m�a�s�-�m�i�c�r�o�s�o�f�t�-�c�o�m�:�o�f�f�i�c�e�:�e�x�c�e�l�"� � �x�m�l�n�s�:�p�=�"�u�r�n�:�s�c�h�e�m�a�s�-�m�i�c�r�o�s�o�f�t�-�c�o�m�:�o�f�f�i�c�e�:�p�o�w�e�r�p�o�i�n�t�"� � �x�m�l�n�s�:�a�=�"�u�r�n�:�s�c�h�e�m�a�s�-�m�i�c�r�o�s�o�f�t�-�c�o�m�:�o�f�f�i�c�e�:�a�c�c�e�s�s�"� �

If any of you guys know this,how can i solve this problem

Comment: What's in sImage?  If it's binary data then text/html is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Jim: It's HTML in UTF-16LE encoding. (Read every second character.)

Comment: Well then Chris Jester-Young's answer is correct.  Setting the content type and character encoding headers don't actually make the output match.  YOU have to do that by setting the appropriate encoding in the writer.  Either set the headers to match the actual data, or convert the data to match the ISO-8859-1 header.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-16LE");
```

Granted, it doesn't make your text ISO-8859-1, but, most browsers have no problem supporting UTF-16 these days.

Comment: @pras: Your browser doesn't like the byte-order mark (BOM)? Try using `UTF-16` instead of `UTF-16LE`. Though, your browser violates RFC 2781, which says that the BOM is supposed to be accepted (but optional) if `UTF-16LE` is used.